# is it possible to run elastic net (lasso) on as few as 8 samples? R

Tags: r, regression, lasso, glmnet, elastic-net

I have 8 samples with outcome 0 or 1 (4 samples of each) and I have 3100 variables, is it possible to run elastic net on these using an alpha of 1 (I just want to use lasso)? And is it possible to do in R?

Comment: Do you mean that your data is a 8x3100 matrix?! You won't get any reasonable results with such data by using automatic variable selection of any kind.

Comment: @Tim They won't get any reasonable results. Period. I would hesitate to use logistic regression with one IV if n is only 8.

Comment: @Roland you could get away with it with a reasonable model and informative priors in Bayesian setting

Comment: @Tim, could you explain a little more?

Comment: @user3324491 explain what exactly?

Comment: @Tim, I mean could you point me in the direction of how I could get away with it in a bayesian setting? I am only familiar with glmnet. Thanks

Comment: @user3324491 first you would have to start with some kind of reasonable model with informative priors -- so it won't work for selecting "the best predictors" from a huge number of variables. It is hard to comment without knowing more about your data.